# The first argument for python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter with python 2.7 and am curious about why the following code snippet would work:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master) # This is where my question is
        self.grid()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

1) The `ttk.Frame.__init__` takes one argument, which is the `master`. But now the first argument is an instance inherited from it, and the second is `master`. How did this work?

2) I noticed that the `ttk.Frame` class also have a function called `mainloop`. How is this different from `root.mainloop()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `ttk.Frame.__init__()` in method `Application.__init__()` is used to initialize base class `ttk.Frame`, the explaination doc is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).

2) `mainloop()` in `ttk.Frame` and `root.mainloop()` is equal, please look at [this](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/the-difference-between-mainloop-and-app-mainloop-and-root-mainloop-td1975563.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the 2nd point! However, for the 1st point, I understand that this is to initialize the base class. However, if I am calling the __init__ of the base class, why would I need to explicitly pass in `self` of the derived class? Isn't the `self` of the base class implicitly called, and all I need is a master argument?

Comment: Because you call `__init__` from class `ttk.Frame` instead of its instance. There is no implicit `self` to use.

Comment: Or you can use another form `super(Application, self).__init__(master) ` to init base class`.

Comment: I see... Thank you so much! This is actually a python class question, not a tkinter then:)